# Double lock screen when resuming after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, suspend, lock-screen

After the upgrade to 15.04 I now get a double lock screen when I wake up from resume. First there will be a centered GTK grey panel which looks a bit like the old switch user login, after I enter that password I'm then presented with a lock screen that is the some one I'll get if I Super+L.

It's not ruining everything, but it's pretty awkward to have to relogin twice on every resume. Any idea how I can disable the first lock screen and just get the Super+L one?

Comment: It appears the first lock is coming from gnome-screensaver... killing it seems to kill the first lock screen. Not sure why both are competing here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug that is known in Ubuntu. More information about the bug can be found here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1296270

In version 16.04 LTS, the solution for me was to uninstall with `sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver`